# sql server user creation for application

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that creates its own users and then these users log in to the application and access the database. How should the users be created, should I have a users table or should I create database level user?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty open ended question, you left out if it's web based or a desktop based application for example - but here are some thoughts.

How many users are you talking and what kind of turnover.  Thousands?  Millions?  Ten?  As the number and/or turnover gets larger and larger the user table looks better and better.  Amazon, for example allows us to create our own shopping cart, be we aren't users on their database server.

For a database internal to a company having database level users usually makes more sense.  It keeps you from having to define a whole security sub-system in your application and ensures that any vulnerabilities have already been addressed by Microsoft and millions of users around the world.

Creating a user table within the database is much simpler up front.  But, it puts a lot of work on the business rules and security sub-system that you'll have to build.  (in addition to mentioned vulnerabilities that it creates)

Meanwhile leveraging database users and roles can be more complex up front (if your doing it from within an application).  You need someone comfortable with tsql, system stored procedures, SMO etc.  But makes managing roles, users, groups, rights etc. a lot easier in the long run with the added benefit that you can manage it all outside of the application if necessary.

Either way your application is going to have to figure out how it uses connection strings.  The database level user route requires connection strings to be specific to each user.  Unless you're planning on using domain accounts with Windows authentication - *which is the way to go whenever possible in my opinion.*